# Quickbooks Webconnector Delays 10+ minutes before each import

Tags: quickbooks

I have a portal that we use to import invoices, customers and vendors into Quickbooks using web connector. The import is successful, however, after we submit each new entry their is a 10+ minute delay from the time we submit to the time the entry is imported into Quickbooks.

Please find my QWC File Code, Que Table and Logs.

[image: enque and deque time showed in quickbooks_que table]

[QWClog File](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1alBu8kRMxhCqZYUG7_gyeiYUs5CFwTP5/view?usp=sharing)

below is my controller i use to import data in quickbooks

```
class QuickBooks extends CI_Controller
{


  public function __construct()
    {
    parent::__construct();

    // QuickBooks config
    $this->load->config('quickbooks');

    // Load your other models here...
    //$this->load->model('yourmodel1');
    //$this->load->model('yourmodel2');
    //$this->load->model('yourmodel3');
}

/**
 * Generate and return a .QWC Web Connector configuration file
 */
public function config()
{
    $name = 'test_site Web Connect';            // A name for your server (make it whatever you want)
    $descrip = 'test_site Web Connect';     // A description of your server

    $appurl = 'https://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . dirname($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']) . '/qbwc';      // This *must* be httpS:// (path to your QuickBooks SOAP server)
    $appsupport = $appurl;      // This *must* be httpS:// and the domain name must match the domain name above

    $username = $this->config->item('quickbooks_user');     // This is the username you stored in the 'quickbooks_user' table by using QuickBooks_Utilities::createUser()

    $fileid = QuickBooks_WebConnector_QWC::fileID();        // Just make this up, but make sure it keeps that format
    $ownerid = QuickBooks_WebConnector_QWC::ownerID();      // Just make this up, but make sure it keeps that format

    $qbtype = QUICKBOOKS_TYPE_QBFS; // You can leave this as-is unless you're using QuickBooks POS

    $readonly = false; // No, we want to write data to QuickBooks

    $run_every_n_seconds = 60; // Run every 60 seconds (1 minute)

    // Generate the XML file
    $QWC = new QuickBooks_WebConnector_QWC($name, $descrip, $appurl, $appsupport, $username, $fileid, $ownerid, $qbtype, $readonly, $run_every_n_seconds);
    $xml = $QWC->generate();

    // Send as a file download
    header('Content-type: text/xml');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="my-quickbooks-wc-file.qwc"');
    print($xml);
    exit;

}

/**
 * SOAP endpoint for the Web Connector to connect to
 */
public function qbwc()
{
    $user = $this->config->item('quickbooks_user');
    $pass = $this->config->item('quickbooks_pass');

    // Memory limit
    ini_set('memory_limit', $this->config->item('quickbooks_memorylimit'));

    // We need to make sure the correct timezone is set, or some PHP installations will complain
    if (function_exists('date_default_timezone_set'))
    {
        // * MAKE SURE YOU SET THIS TO THE CORRECT TIMEZONE! *
        // List of valid timezones is here: http://us3.php.net/manual/en/timezones.php
        date_default_timezone_set($this->config->item('quickbooks_tz'));
    }


    // Build the database connection string
    //$dsn = 'mysqli://devstagetest_site_qbuser:6Y_9aI@PBSrF@50.62.57.212/devstagetest_site_qb_database'; // dev
    $dsn = 'mysqli://test_site_qbuser:r1R1aQ;gcE%;@50.62.57.212/test_site_qb_database'; // live


    // Map QuickBooks actions to handler functions
    $map = array(
        QUICKBOOKS_ADD_CUSTOMER => array( array( $this, '_addCustomerRequest' ), array( $this, '_addCustomerResponse' ) ),
        QUICKBOOKS_ADD_INVOICE => array( array( $this, '_invoice_add_request' ), array( $this, '_invoice_add_response' ) ),
        QUICKBOOKS_ADD_VENDOR => array( array( $this, '_vendor_add_request' ), array( $this, '_vendor_add_response' ) ),
    );

    // Catch all errors that QuickBooks throws with this function
    $errmap = array(
        3070 => array( $this,'_quickbooks_error_stringtoolong'),
        'InvoiceAdd' => array( $this,'_quickbooks_error_invoiceadd'),
        'CustomerAdd' => array( $this,'_quickbooks_error_customeradd'),
        'VendorAdd' => array( $this,'_quickbooks_error_vendoradd'),
        500 => array( $this,'cust_not_exist'),
        3100 => array( $this,'cust_already_exist'),
        '*' => array( $this, '_catchallErrors' ),
    );

    // Call this method whenever the Web Connector connects
    $hooks = array(
        //QuickBooks_WebConnector_Handlers::HOOK_LOGINSUCCESS => array( array( $this, '_loginSuccess' ) ),  // Run this function whenever a successful login occurs
    );
    // An array of callback options
    $callback_options = array();

    // Logging level
    $log_level = $this->config->item('quickbooks_loglevel');

    // What SOAP server you're using
    //$soapserver = QUICKBOOKS_SOAPSERVER_PHP;          // The PHP SOAP extension, see: www.php.net/soap
    $soapserver = QUICKBOOKS_SOAPSERVER_BUILTIN;        // A pure-PHP SOAP server (no PHP ext/soap extension required, also makes debugging easier)

    $soap_options = array(      // See http://www.php.net/soap
    );

    $handler_options = array(
        'deny_concurrent_logins' => false,
    );      // See the comments in the QuickBooks/Server/Handlers.php file

    $driver_options = array(        // See the comments in the QuickBooks/Driver/<YOUR DRIVER HERE>.php file ( i.e. 'Mysql.php', etc. )
        'max_log_history' => 32000, // Limit the number of quickbooks_log entries to 1024
        'max_queue_history' => 1024,    // Limit the number of *successfully processed* quickbooks_queue entries to 64
    );



    // Check to make sure our database is set up
    if (!QuickBooks_Utilities::initialized($dsn))
    {
        // Initialize creates the neccessary database schema for queueing up requests and logging
        QuickBooks_Utilities::initialize($dsn);

        // This creates a username and password which is used by the Web Connector to authenticate
        QuickBooks_Utilities::createUser($dsn, $user, $pass);
    }

    // Set up our queue singleton
    QuickBooks_WebConnector_Queue_Singleton::initialize($dsn);

    // Create a new server and tell it to handle the requests
    // __construct($dsn_or_conn, $map, $errmap = array(), $hooks = array(), $log_level = QUICKBOOKS_LOG_NORMAL, $soap = QUICKBOOKS_SOAPSERVER_PHP, $wsdl = QUICKBOOKS_WSDL, $soap_options = array(), $handler_options = array(), $driver_options = array(), $callback_options = array()
    $Server = new QuickBooks_WebConnector_Server($dsn, $map, $errmap, $hooks, $log_level, $soapserver, QUICKBOOKS_WSDL, $soap_options, $handler_options, $driver_options, $callback_options);
    $response = $Server->handle(true, true);
}

function _invoice_add_request($requestID, $user, $action, $ID, $extra, &$err, $last_action_time, $last_actionident_time, $version, $locale) {

    $record = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM qb_add_invoice WHERE id = '".$ID."'")->row();
    if(count($record)>0){
        $orderid = $record->orderID;
        $uordername = $record->uordername;
        $xplode_data = explode("_", $uordername);
        $sendfrom = $record->sendfrom;
        $notary_fee = $record->notary_fee;
        $test_site_fee = $record->test_site_fee;

        $orders_record = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM orders WHERE orderID = '".$orderid."'")->row();
        $Addr1 ='';
        $Addr2 = '';

        if($sendfrom == 'Notary'){
            $notary_record = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM notaryRegis WHERE notaryID = '".$orders_record->notaryID."'")->row();
            if($notary_record->state > 0){
                $stateRow = $this->db->query("select * from state where stateID = '".$notary_record->state."'")->row();
                $stateName= $stateRow->stateName;
            }
            else {
                $stateName= "";
            }

            $FullName = trim($notary_record->lastName).', '.trim($notary_record->firstName);

            $Addr1 =$FullName;
            $Addr2 = $notary_record->streetAddress;
            $City = $notary_record->city;
            $State = $stateName;
            $PostalCode = $notary_record->zip;
            $PONumber = $notary_record->lastName;
            $Rate = number_format((float)$notary_fee, 2, '.', '');;
        }
        else if($sendfrom == 'Client'){
            $client_record = $this->db->query("SELECT 
                                                        cr. *,
                                                        zf.fee AS client_test_site_fee 
                                                    FROM 
                                                        customer_table cr
                                                    LEFT JOIN test_site_fees zf
                                                        ON(cr.serviceType = zf.type)
                                                    WHERE 
                                                        cr.clientID = '".$orders_record->clientID."'")->row();



            $FullName = trim($client_record->company).'-'.trim($client_record->firstName).' '.trim($client_record->lastName);
            $Addr1 = substr($client_record->mailingAddress, 0, 39);
            $Addr2 = '';
            $City = $client_record->city;
            $State = $client_record->state;
            $PostalCode = $client_record->zip;
            $PONumber = $orders_record->customerLastName;
            $Rate = $notary_fee+$client_record->client_test_site_fee;
        }
        $TxnDate = explode(" ",$orders_record->RequestedAppointmentDate);
        $TxnDate = $TxnDate[0];

        if($TxnDate == '0000-00-00'){
            $TxnDate = date('Y-m-d');
        }else{
            $TxnDate = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($TxnDate));

        }

        $RefNumber = $orders_record->escrowNumber;
        $Bill = $orders_record->loanPackageType;

        if($sendfrom == 'Client'){
            /*  $xml = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
                            <?qbxml version="13.0"?>
                            <QBXML>
                                <QBXMLMsgsRq onError="continueOnError">
                                    <InvoiceAddRq requestID="' . $requestID . '">
                                        <InvoiceAdd>
                                            <CustomerRef>
                                                <FullName>'.$FullName.'</FullName>
                                            </CustomerRef>
                                            <TxnDate>'.$TxnDate.'</TxnDate>
                                            <RefNumber>' . $RefNumber.'</RefNumber>
                                            <BillAddress>
                                                <Addr1>'.$FullName.'</Addr1>
                                                <Addr2>'.$Addr1.'</Addr2>
                                                <City>'.$City.'</City>
                                                <State>'.$State.'</State>
                                                <PostalCode>'.$PostalCode.'</PostalCode>
                                                <Country></Country>
                                            </BillAddress>
                                            <PONumber>'.$orders_record->customerLastName.'</PONumber>                               
                                            <TermsRef>
                                                <FullName>'.$FullName.'</FullName>
                                            </TermsRef>
                                            <DueDate>' . $TxnDate . '</DueDate>
                                            <InvoiceLineAdd>
                                                <ItemRef>
                                                    <FullName>Bill:test_site Fee</FullName>
                                                </ItemRef>
                                                <Rate>' . $Rate.'</Rate>
                                            </InvoiceLineAdd>
                                        </InvoiceAdd>
                                    </InvoiceAddRq>
                                </QBXMLMsgsRq>
                            </QBXML>';
                */

            $xml = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
                            <?qbxml version="2.0"?>
                            <QBXML>
                                <QBXMLMsgsRq onError="stopOnError">
                                    <InvoiceAddRq requestID="' . $requestID . '">
                                        <InvoiceAdd>
                                            <CustomerRef>
                                                <FullName>'.$FullName.'</FullName>
                                            </CustomerRef>
                                            <TxnDate>' . $TxnDate . '</TxnDate>
                                            <RefNumber>' . $RefNumber.'</RefNumber>
                                            <ShipAddress>
                                                <Addr1>'.trim($orders_record->customerFirstName).' '.trim($orders_record->customerLastName).'</Addr1>
                                                <Addr2>'.$orders_record->signingAddress.'</Addr2>
                                                <City>'.$orders_record->city.'</City>
                                                <State>'.$this->db->get_where('state', "stateID = $orders_record->state", 1)->row()->stateName.'</State>
                                                <PostalCode>'.$orders_record->zip.'</PostalCode>
                                                <Country></Country>
                                            </ShipAddress>
                                            <PONumber>'.$orders_record->customerLastName.'</PONumber>
                                                <TermsRef>
                                                    <FullName>Net 30</FullName>
                                                </TermsRef>
                                            <DueDate>' . $TxnDate . '</DueDate>
                                            <InvoiceLineAdd>
                                                <ItemRef>
                                                    <FullName>test_site Fee</FullName>
                                                </ItemRef>
                                                <Rate>' . $Rate.'</Rate>
                                            </InvoiceLineAdd>
                                        </InvoiceAdd>
                                    </InvoiceAddRq>
                                </QBXMLMsgsRq>
                            </QBXML>';



        }
        else if($sendfrom == 'Notary'){
            $xml = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
                        <?qbxml version="2.0"?>
                        <QBXML>
                            <QBXMLMsgsRq onError="continueOnError">
                                <BillAddRq requestID="' . $requestID . '">
                                    <BillAdd>
                                        <VendorRef>
                                            <FullName>' .$FullName.'</FullName>
                                        </VendorRef>
                                        <TxnDate>' . $TxnDate . '</TxnDate>
                                        <DueDate>' . $TxnDate . '</DueDate>
                                        <RefNumber>' . $RefNumber.'</RefNumber>
                                            <TermsRef>
                                                <FullName>Net 15</FullName>
                                            </TermsRef>
                                        <ExpenseLineAdd>
                                            <AccountRef>
                                            <FullName>Outside Services:Loan Signing Fee</FullName>
                                            </AccountRef>
                                            <Amount>' . $Rate.'</Amount>
                                        </ExpenseLineAdd>
                                    </BillAdd>
                                </BillAddRq>
                            </QBXMLMsgsRq>
                        </QBXML>';


        }


        /*$this->email->from('info@test_site.com');
       $this->email->to('jaihind530@gmail.com');
       $this->email->cc('shehrozasmat005@gmail.com');
       $this->email->subject("test_site : invoice XML");
       $this->email->message($xml);
       $this->email->send();*/

        // storing xml for the loging



        return $xml;

    }
    else {
        $this->db->query("DELETE from qb_add_invoice WHERE id = '".$ID."'");
        return true;
    }

}


public function _invoice_add_response($requestID, $user, $action, $ID, $extra, &$err, $last_action_time, $last_actionident_time, $xml, $idents)
{
    $this->db->query("UPDATE qb_add_invoice SET status=1, updated_at = '".date("Y-m-d H:i:s")."' WHERE id = '".$ID."'");

    $record = $this->db->query("SELECT sendfrom,orderID FROM qb_add_invoice WHERE id = '".$ID."'")->row();
    $orecord = $this->db->query("SELECT clientID,notaryID FROM orders WHERE orderID = '".$record->orderID."'")->row();
    if($record->sendfrom == 'Notary'){
        $crecord = $this->db->query("SELECT firstName,lastName FROM notaryRegis WHERE notaryID = '".$orecord->notaryID."'")->row();
    }
    else {
        $crecord = $this->db->query("SELECT firstName,lastName FROM customer_table WHERE clientID = '".$orecord->clientID."'")->row();
    }

    return "";
}

function _quickbooks_error_invoiceadd($requestID, $user, $action, $ID, $extra, &$err, $xml, $errnum, $errmsg) {

    $this->db->query("DELETE from qb_add_invoice WHERE id = '".$ID."'");
    return false;
}

/**
 * Issue a request to QuickBooks to add a customer
 */
public function _addCustomerRequest($requestID, $user, $action, $ID, $extra, &$err, $last_action_time, $last_actionident_time, $version, $locale)
{
    $qb_add_cust = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM qb_add_cust WHERE id = '".$ID."'")->row();
    $record = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM customer_table WHERE clientID = '".$qb_add_cust->clientID."'")->row();
    if(count($record)>0){
        // Build the qbXML request from $data
        $xml = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
        <?qbxml version="2.0"?>
        <QBXML>
            <QBXMLMsgsRq onError="continueOnError">
                <CustomerAddRq requestID="' . $requestID . '">
                    <CustomerAdd>
                        <Name>'.trim($record->company).'-'.trim($record->firstName).' '.trim($record->lastName).'</Name>
                        <CompanyName>' . trim($record->company) . '</CompanyName>
                        <FirstName>'.trim($record->firstName).'</FirstName>
                        <LastName>'.trim($record->lastName).'</LastName>
                        <BillAddress>
                            <Addr1>'.trim(substr($record->mailingAddress,0,39)).'</Addr1>
                            <Addr2></Addr2>
                            <City>'.trim($record->city).'</City>
                            <State>'.trim($record->state).'</State>
                            <PostalCode>'.trim($record->zip).'</PostalCode>
                            <Country></Country>
                        </BillAddress>
                        <Phone>'.$record->businessPhone.'</Phone>
                        <AltPhone></AltPhone>
                        <Fax></Fax>
                        <Email>'.$record->email.'</Email>                       
                    </CustomerAdd>
                </CustomerAddRq>
            </QBXMLMsgsRq>
        </QBXML>';

        // storing xml for the loging


        return $xml;
    }
    else {

        //$this->db->query("DELETE from qb_add_cust WHERE id = '".$ID."'");
        return true;
    }
}

/**
 * Handle a response from QuickBooks indicating a new customer has been added
 */
public function _addCustomerResponse($requestID, $user, $action, $ID, $extra, &$err, $last_action_time, $last_actionident_time, $xml, $idents)
{


    $this->db->query("UPDATE qb_add_cust SET ListID = '".$idents['ListID']."' , status=1, updated_at = '".date("Y-m-d H:i:s")."' WHERE id = '".$ID."'");

    $qb_add_cust = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM qb_add_cust WHERE id = '".$ID."'")->row();

    $record = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM customer_table WHERE clientID = '".$qb_add_cust->clientID."'")->row();

    return true;
}

function _quickbooks_error_customeradd($requestID, $user, $action, $ID, $extra, &$err, $xml, $errnum, $errmsg) {



    $this->db->query("DELETE from qb_add_cust WHERE id = '".$ID."'");

    return true;
}

function _vendor_add_request($requestID, $user, $action, $ID, $extra, & $err, $last_action_time, $last_actionident_time, $xml, $idents)
{
    $qb_add_vendor = $this->db->get_where("qb_add_vendor", "id = $ID")->row();

    /*$ins['request_id'] = $requestID;
    $ins['import'] = $ID;
    $ins['operation_xml'] = implode('==',$qb_add_vendor);
    $ins['operation_type'] = 'pre_add_vendor_failed';
    $this->db->insert('qb_operations_xml_response', $ins);*/

    $record = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM notaryRegis WHERE notaryID = '".$qb_add_vendor->notaryID."'")->row();

    if(!empty($record)){
        $pay = "";
        $cell = $record->phone;

        if($record->state > 0){
            $stateRow = $this->db->query("select * from state where stateID = '".$record->state."'")->row();
            $stateName= $stateRow->stateName;
        }
        else {
            $stateName= "";
        }

        $address1 = str_replace('-', ' ',$record->streetAddress);
        $address2 = '';
        $city     = $record->city;

        $zip1     = $record->zip;

        // Create and return a qbXML request
        $xml = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
                    <?qbxml version="13.0"?>
                    <QBXML>
                        <QBXMLMsgsRq onError="StopOnError">
                            <VendorAddRq requestID="' . $requestID . '">
                                <VendorAdd>
                                    <Name>' .trim($record->lastName).', '.trim($record->firstName).'</Name>
                                    <CompanyName></CompanyName>
                                    <FirstName>'.trim($record->firstName).'</FirstName>
                                    <LastName>'.trim($record->lastName).'</LastName>
                                    <VendorAddress>
                                        <Addr1>'.trim($record->firstName).' '.trim($record->lastName).'</Addr1>
                                        <Addr2>'.substr($address1,0, 35).'</Addr2>
                                        <Addr3></Addr3>
                                        <City>'.$city.'</City>
                                        <State>'.$stateName.'</State>
                                        <PostalCode>'.$zip1.'</PostalCode>
                                        <Country></Country>
                                    </VendorAddress>
                                    <Phone>'.$cell.'</Phone>
                                    <AltPhone></AltPhone>
                                    <Fax></Fax>
                                    <Email>'.$record->email.'</Email>
                                    <VendorTaxIdent></VendorTaxIdent>
                                    <IsVendorEligibleFor1099>true</IsVendorEligibleFor1099>
                                </VendorAdd>
                            </VendorAddRq>
                        </QBXMLMsgsRq>
                    </QBXML>';

        // storing xml for the loging



        return $xml;
    }
    else
    {

        $this->db->query("DELETE from qb_add_vendor WHERE id = '".$ID."'");
        return "";

    }




}

function _vendor_add_response($requestID, $user, $action, $ID, $extra, &$err, $last_action_time, $last_actionident_time, $xml, $idents)
{


    $this->db->query("UPDATE qb_add_vendor SET ListID = '".$idents['ListID']."' , status=1, updated_at = '".date("Y-m-d H:i:s")."' WHERE id = '".$ID."'");
    $qb_add_vendor = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM qb_add_vendor WHERE id = '".$ID."'")->row();

    $ins['request_id'] = $requestID;
    $ins['import'] = $ID;
    $ins['operation_xml'] = implode('==', $qb_add_vendor);
    $ins['operation_type'] = 'add_vendor_response';
    $this->db->insert('qb_operations_xml_response', $ins);

    $record = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM notaryRegis WHERE notaryID = '".$qb_add_vendor->notaryID."'")->row();

    return "";
}

function _quickbooks_error_vendoradd($requestID, $user, $action, $ID, $extra, &$err, $xml, $errnum, $errmsg)
{

    $this->db->query("DELETE from qb_add_vendor WHERE id = '".$ID."'");
    return false;
}


function _quickbooks_error_stringtoolong($requestID, $user, $action, $ID, $extra, &$err, $xml, $errnum, $errmsg)
{
    if($action == "InvoiceAdd")
    {
        $sql1="DELETE from qb_add_invoice WHERE id = '".$ID."'";
    }
    if($action == "CustomerAdd")
    {
        $sql1="DELETE from  qb_add_cust WHERE id = '".$ID."'";

    }
    if($action == "VendorAdd")
    {
        $sql1="DELETE from  qb_add_vendor WHERE id = '".$ID."'";
    }

    return true;
}


/**
 * Catch and handle errors from QuickBooks
 */
public function _catchallErrors($requestID, $user, $action, $ID, $extra, &$err, $xml, $errnum, $errmsg)
{
    if($action == "InvoiceAdd")
    {
        $sql1="DELETE from qb_add_invoice WHERE id = '".$ID."'";
    }
    if($action == "CustomerAdd")
    {
        $sql1="DELETE from  qb_add_cust WHERE id = '".$ID."'";

    }
    if($action == "VendorAdd")
    {
        $sql1="DELETE from  qb_add_vendor WHERE id = '".$ID."'";
    }

    $this->db->query($sql1);

    $admin_template = '<p>'.$errmsg.'</p>';
    $this->email->from('info@test_site.com');
    $this->email->to('adam@test_site.com');
    $this->email->subject('test_site : Error to send in Quickbooks');
    $this->email->message($admin_template);
    $this->email->send();

    return true;
}

function cust_already_exist($requestID, $user, $action, $ID, $extra, &$err, $xml, $errnum, $errmsg)
{

    $qb_add_cust = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM qb_add_cust WHERE id = '".$ID."'")->row();

    $customer_table = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM customer_table WHERE clientID = '" .$qb_add_cust->clientID."'")->row();


    $this->db->query("UPDATE qb_add_cust SET status=1, updated_at = '".date("Y-m-d H:i:s")."' WHERE id = '".$ID."'");
    return true;
}

function cust_not_exist($requestID, $user, $action, $ID, $extra, &$err, $xml, $errnum, $errmsg)
{

    $this->db->query("DELETE from qb_add_invoice WHERE id = '".$ID."'");
    return true;
}

/**
 * Whenever the Web Connector connects, do something (e.g. queue some stuff up if you want to)
 */
public function _loginSuccess($requestID, $user, $hook, &$err, $hook_data, $callback_config)
{
    return true;
    }
}
```

[image: complete que entries from the que table]

Comment: Post your code. Post the rest of the queue so we can actually see what's going on.

Comment: @KeithPalmerJr. I have just added my controller code kindly have  a look at it let me know if you want to know anything else.

Comment: Post the rest of the queue.

Comment: @KeithPalmerJr. i have added the image for the all the entries from the que in database

Comment: @KeithPalmerJr. can you please be kind enough to respond on this ?

Comment: "Help me, @KeithPalmerJr. You're my only hope."